# in relation to loading jquery into a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Could someone help me with this code?

In my Rails project (I don't think it matters what project it is) I have a header that is fixed in position, called 'fixed_header'. There are links on this page, which load new pages underneath, when clicked.

One of the pages which loads, when clicked, has a div called 'map_canvas'. I want the code in my 'fixed_header' page to check for the existence of a div called 'map_canvas', and then, if it is there, load a map into it.

My code below is taken from snippets throughout my application, which work, but I can't make it work for this particular thing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>

  //Is 'ready' the code to use? This code is in 'fixed_header'
  //My idea is that, once 
  //a link in 'fixed_header' is clicked, a new page loads
  //underneath the header. The div 'map_canvas' is
  //searched for and the function activates if it is found.

    $(document).on("ready", function () {

        if ($("#map_canvas").length > 0) {

            initialize_google_maps();

        }

    });

    function initialize_google_maps() {

        var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);
        var zoom = 10;
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: currentlatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
            streetViewControl: false
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: currentlatlng,
            icon: {
                oppacity: 0
            }
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            fillOpacity: 0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            radius: 10000,
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "_I can't make it work_" isn't that acurate. What is the acutal problem? How do you load the new page content, normal links with page refresh or ajax?

Comment: I use ajax. But I've been having so much trouble with script tags being stripped etc, it's been a real headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to check the div existence in real time when user clicks on link the you should change your code

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {

        if ($("#map_canvas").length > 0) {

            initialize_google_maps();

        }

    });
```

as below

```
$('a').live('click',function() {
        if ($("#map_canvas").length > 0) {

            initialize_google_maps();

        }
}
```

use the anchor selector according to your link classes or ids.

Comment: `live` is deprecated use i.e. `$('#fixed_header').on('click', 'a', function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Thanks Marcel Gwerder for telling.

Comment: Problems with the above is that the link that loads 'map_canvas' needs to be clicked twice for it to work. It is only with the second click when it goes, 'Ah, there a page with the div called 'map_canvas' here. I'll load the map into it' Is it possible to have it work first time round?

Comment: This all depends on how you load your content. If this are standard links with page refresh. You'll be ok with `$(document).on('ready')`. If you load your content with ajax you have to do the check and gmaps initialization in the ajax callback.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I think some Ajax thing meant I had to click twice. In fact your code was right. I've accepted your answer and marked up Marcel  for the comment